# Marginal correlations from lmer

Tags: r, correlation, lme4-nlme, panel-data

In the book "Applied Longitudinal Analysis" by Fitzmaurice et. al (2012), they fit a model for the six cities study as follows:

```r
require(dplyr)
require(ALA)
require(lmerTest)
data(fev1, package = "ALA")
fev1 %<>% filter(id != 197)
fev1 %<>% mutate(
  loght = log(height),
  logbht = log(height0)
) 
model_1 = lmer(logFEV1 ~ age + loght + age0 + logbht + (1 + age | id),
               data = fev1)
```

This fits a mixed effects model between `logFEV1` and some covariates. They then produce the following table (Table 8.4, p. 219 in the book):

[image: Marginal correlations]

1. What are the interpretation of these marginal correlations, and how are they actually calculated? The book says they are functions of the covariance matrix of the random effects and the residual variance, but gives no more information that.
2. Is there a way to obtain these correlations within R from the fitted `lmer` model?

Comment: Your code doesn't run without loading a package that provides `%<>%`, probably `magrittr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book does give the formula for the marginal covariance (matrix) of the response $Y_i$ of individual $i$ (several times, f.i. on page 201):
$$
\Sigma_i=\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i)=Z_iG{Z}^{\top}_i+R_i\overset{\text{typically}}{=}Z_iG{Z}^{\top}_i + \sigma^2I_{n_i},
$$
where $R_i$ is the covariance matrix of the measurement errors, $Z_i$ the design matrix and $G$ the covariance matrix of the individual-specific/random effects $b_i$.

Entry $(k,l)$ of $\Sigma_i$ gives you the marginal covariance between observation $k$ and observation $l$ of individual $i$. 'Marginal' means averaged over the (distribution of the) random effects.$^\star$

Clearly, the corresponding correlation matrix is given by
$$
\mathrm{Corr}(Y_i)=S_i\mathrm{Cov}(Y_i)S_i,
$$

where $S_i=\mathrm{diag}[(\Sigma_i)_{11},\ldots,(\Sigma_i)_{n_in_i}]^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, i.e. $S_i$ is a diagonal matrix with the reciprocals of the marginal standard deviations extracted from $\Sigma_i$ on the diagonal.

---

$^\star$Here averaging can be understood as calculating the respective expectations in [the law of total covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance) applied to $\Sigma_i$, where $b_i$ is the conditioning variable.

---

Judging from the [book's website](https://content.sph.harvard.edu/fitzmaur/ala2e/sect8_8a.html), I think Table 8.4 shows the *estimated* marginal correlation matrix of $\log(\mathrm{FEV}_1)$ *for individual 35*.

The code below calculates the estimated marginal correlation matrix for all individuals and then extracts only the block corresponding to individual 35. Details can be found in [one of the `lme4` vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf). I've added the age as column and row names for illustration purposes.

```
corr_marginal <- function(lmm) {
  Z <- getME(lmm, "Z")
  V <- sigma(lmm)^2 * (Z %*% tcrossprod(getME(lmm, "Lambda")) %*% t(Z) + 
                       Diagonal(getME(lmm, "n")))
  cov2cor(V)
}

rows_35 <- fev1$id == 35
corr_marginal(model_1)[rows_35, rows_35] %>%
  round(2) %>% 
  as.matrix() %>% 
  'colnames<-' (fev1$age[rows_35]) %>% 
  'rownames<-' (colnames(.))
#         7.0171 7.9945 8.9829 10.037 11.0773 12.0876 13.0623 14.1547 15.0773 16.1478 17.0103 18.0068
# 7.0171    1.00   0.70   0.69   0.68    0.67    0.66    0.64    0.62    0.60    0.58    0.56    0.54
# 7.9945    0.70   1.00   0.70   0.69    0.68    0.67    0.66    0.65    0.63    0.61    0.60    0.58
# 8.9829    0.69   0.70   1.00   0.70    0.69    0.69    0.68    0.67    0.66    0.64    0.63    0.61
# 10.037    0.68   0.69   0.70   1.00    0.70    0.70    0.70    0.69    0.68    0.67    0.66    0.64
# 11.0773   0.67   0.68   0.69   0.70    1.00    0.71    0.71    0.70    0.70    0.69    0.68    0.67
# 12.0876   0.66   0.67   0.69   0.70    0.71    1.00    0.72    0.72    0.71    0.71    0.70    0.70
# 13.0623   0.64   0.66   0.68   0.70    0.71    0.72    1.00    0.73    0.73    0.73    0.72    0.72
# 14.1547   0.62   0.65   0.67   0.69    0.70    0.72    0.73    1.00    0.74    0.74    0.74    0.74
# 15.0773   0.60   0.63   0.66   0.68    0.70    0.71    0.73    0.74    1.00    0.75    0.75    0.75
# 16.1478   0.58   0.61   0.64   0.67    0.69    0.71    0.73    0.74    0.75    1.00    0.76    0.76
# 17.0103   0.56   0.60   0.63   0.66    0.68    0.70    0.72    0.74    0.75    0.76    1.00    0.77
# 18.0068   0.54   0.58   0.61   0.64    0.67    0.70    0.72    0.74    0.75    0.76    0.77    1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $\text{Cov}(\mathbf{Y}_i)$ is a function of time, $\mathbf{t}_i$.

```
Z <- fev1 |> 
  arrange(id, age) |> 
  filter(id == '35') |> 
  select(age) |> 
  mutate(intercept = 1, .before = age) |> 
  as.matrix()
Zt <- t(Z)
G <- VarCorr(model_1)[[1]]
sigma2 <- summary(model_1)$sigma^2
Isigma2 <- diag(1, nrow = 12) * sigma2
cov_y <- Z %*% G %*% Zt + Isigma2
cov2cor(cov_y)
```

You can check the results with the SAS output in the book's web page